# XXHash - Java vs. PHP

Tags: java, php

I get different results everytime when using XXHash library in PHP and Java (this implementation: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Zero-Allocation-Hashing).

**Java**

```
Log.e('xx128low', Long.toHexString(LongHashFunction.xx128low().hashChars("12345")));
Log.e('xx', Long.toHexString(LongHashFunction.xx().hashChars("12345")));
Log.e('xx3', Long.toHexString(LongHashFunction.xx3().hashChars("12345")));
```

*Results:*

```
E/xx128low: ee40efb40996b83a
E/xx: 807d4a5b54b8db4
E/xx3: 3a4df7c76c99039
```

**PHP**

```
var_dump(hash('xxh128', (string)12345));
var_dump(hash('xxh64', (string)12345));
var_dump(hash('xxh3', (string)12345));
```

*Results:*

```
string(32) "4af3da69f61e14cf26f4c14b6b6bfdb4"
string(16) "c6f2d2dd0ad64fb6"
string(16) "f34099ede96b5581"
```

I can't spot the issue. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: I'm going to say that it's the Java side that's giving incorrect values, since PHP and Python hashes agree.

Comment: @Sammitch Good point, didn't check that...

Comment: Also worth noting that the PHP algos are `xxh3_128`, `xxh_64`, and `xxh3_64` respectively, and I can't make heads or tails of what `xx128low` is supposed to be in the Java code. Maybe the "low" half of a 128-bit hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the variants of `hash('xxh3', (string) 12345)` might look like this.

```java
public static String hexToString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hexString.append('0');
            }
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

        return hexString.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] longToBytesArray(long x) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
        buffer.putLong(x);
        return buffer.array();
    }


    public static String hashingXxh3() throws IOException {
        long hashing = LongHashFunction.xx3().hashBytes("12345".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String toHexStr = hexToString(longToBytesArray(hashing));

        return toHexStr;
    }
```

The value it returns is the same value returned from `hash('xxh3', (string) 12345)` in PHP.

> [image: screenshot]